# Calling map_async within a thread not working

Tags: python, multiprocessing

using the multiprocessing pool in python
This is what I'm trying to do:

```
def do_task(data):
   print "Executing: " + data
   return data

def do_something(data):
   print "Starting do_something"
   result2 = pool.map_async(do_task, ["AA","BB"])  
   print "before get"
   result2.get()
   print "after get"
   return data

def main():
    pool = Pool(processes=4)             
    result = pool.apply_async(do_something, "A")  
    print result.get()
```

But it doesn't work here the output:

```
Starting do_something
before get
```

it stays stuck here and do_task is never called. Ca someone explain me why?
Thank you

Comment: Well, you never call `do_task`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Johny19
That code (by removing the typo papachino pointed out works fine
I think somewhere in your code you forgot or call at the wrong time the .close() attribute...

Comment: Omg yes you are right at the bottom on my code there a close that was called before the job had a chance to finish....

Answer (score 0):

Is it a typo ? Shouldn't it be result2.get()